# TestNG 'dependsOnMethods' stops 'thread-count' from working?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

TestNG 'dependsOnMethods' stops 'thread-count' from working?

I have x3 TestNG classes that use depends on method as listed:

1st Class:

```
public class AddABookingTest extends BrowserFactory {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void load_BookingSystemHomepage() throws Exception {
        supplierHome_BookingSystem_Page.loadBookingSystemHomePage();
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, dependsOnMethods={"load_BookingSystemHomepage"})
    public void enter_UserLoginDetails_Login_Page() throws Exception {
        basePage.sendKeysToWebElement(login_BookingSystem_Page.textField_UserName, "x");
        basePage.sendKeysToWebElement(login_BookingSystem_Page.textField_Password, "xx");
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, dependsOnMethods={"load_BookingSystemHomepage", "enter_UserLoginDetails_Login_Page"})
    public void clickOn_Login_Button() throws Exception {
        basePage.waitAndClickElement(login_BookingSystem_Page.button_Login);
    }
```

2nd Class:

```
public class AddABookingTest2 extends BrowserFactory {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void load_BookingSystemHomepage() throws Exception {
        supplierHome_BookingSystem_Page.loadBookingSystemHomePage();
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, dependsOnMethods={"load_BookingSystemHomepage"})
    public void enter_UserLoginDetails_Login_Page() throws Exception {
        basePage.sendKeysToWebElement(login_BookingSystem_Page.textField_UserName, "x");
        basePage.sendKeysToWebElement(login_BookingSystem_Page.textField_Password, "xx");
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, dependsOnMethods={"load_BookingSystemHomepage", "enter_UserLoginDetails_Login_Page"})
    public void clickOn_Login_Button() throws Exception {
        basePage.waitAndClickElement(login_BookingSystem_Page.button_Login);
    }
```

3rd Class:

```
public class AddABookingTest3 extends BrowserFactory {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void load_BookingSystemHomepage() throws Exception {
        supplierHome_BookingSystem_Page.loadBookingSystemHomePage();
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, dependsOnMethods={"load_BookingSystemHomepage"})
    public void enter_UserLoginDetails_Login_Page() throws Exception {
        basePage.sendKeysToWebElement(login_BookingSystem_Page.textField_UserName, "x");
        basePage.sendKeysToWebElement(login_BookingSystem_Page.textField_Password, "xx");
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, dependsOnMethods={"load_BookingSystemHomepage", "enter_UserLoginDetails_Login_Page"})
    public void clickOn_Login_Button() throws Exception {
        basePage.waitAndClickElement(login_BookingSystem_Page.button_Login);
    }
```

When executing my TestNG XML file, all x3 classes seem to open at the same time, even when i have set the thread count to 2, if i remove all depends-on, everything works correctly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Automation_Scripts_by_GBruno" verbose="2"  parallel="classes" thread-count="2">

    <test name="Automation Tests">
        <packages>
            <package name="Framework.complete.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**NEW CODE:**

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<test name="Framework Automation Tests">
    <packages>
        <package name="Framework.url2.*"></package>
    </packages>
</test>
```

Test class 1:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Framework.utilities.BrowserFactory;

public class UrlCheckerTest extends BrowserFactory {
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void checkURL_Test1() throws Exception {
        getDriver().get("https://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void checkURL_Test2() throws Exception {
        getDriver().get("https://www.amazon.com");
    }
}
```

Test Class2:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Framework.utilities.BrowserFactory;

public class UrlCheckerTest2 extends BrowserFactory {
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void checkURL_Test1() throws Exception {
        getDriver().get("https://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void checkURL_Test2() throws Exception {
        getDriver().get("https://www.amazon.com");
    }
}
```

Test3:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Framework.utilities.BrowserFactory;

public class UrlCheckerTest extends BrowserFactory {
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void checkURL_Test1() throws Exception {
        getDriver().get("https://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void checkURL_Test2() throws Exception {
        getDriver().get("https://www.amazon.com");
    }
}
```

Test4:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Framework.utilities.BrowserFactory;

public class UrlCheckerTest extends BrowserFactory {
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void checkURL_Test1() throws Exception {
        getDriver().get("https://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void checkURL_Test2() throws Exception {
        getDriver().get("https://www.amazon.com");
    }
}
```

Browser Factory:
    protected WebDriver webdriver;

```
public WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
        try {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(Base_Page.getConstant(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY));
            p.load(fi);

            String browserName = p.getProperty("browser");
            switch (browserName) {

            //firefox setup
            case "firefox":
                if (null == webdriver) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Base_Page.getConstant(Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY));
                    webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
                }
                break;

           //chrome setup
            case "chrome":
                if (null == webdriver) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Base_Page.getConstant(Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY));
                    webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
                }
                break;

           //IE setup   
            case "ie":
                if (null == webdriver) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Base_Page.getConstant(Constant.IE_DRIVER_DIRECTORY));
                    webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                }
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load browser! - Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return webdriver;
    }



@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void quitDriver() throws Exception {
        if (null != webdriver) {
            getDriver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
            webdriver.close();
            webdriver.quit();
            webdriver = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This a issue in testng and not yet resolved. https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1185

Comment: @Murthi thanks for the comment

Comment: @xGIx - I dont think this issue is related to #1185. I tried to reproduce this issue with TestNG 6.11 ( the latest released version of TestNG ) and I can't reproduce the problem. See this [gist post](https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/fa7ab905b09f84206d7c4af0c10e9d8c) for details of the class, the suite xml and the output.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan even when i upgraded to the latest version of TestNG(6.11) and also removed the depends-on-methods setup my tests seem to execute more than x2 threads at a time even though i have configure a max of x2 threads in the XML, any ideas?

Comment: @xGIx - Would you be able to help provide a simple example which I can execute to recreate the problem ? The sample that you have provided in your question cannot be executed by me without getting hold of all the other classes. It would be great if you could please help trim it down to a simple class and also include the corresponding xml.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan I will add the code now

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan I have added the new code, thanks